# Get all Youtube videos in a Youtube Playlist including the duration of it

Tags: c#, asynchronous, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I need to get the duration of each Video in a Playlist, the problem is that there is no duration included, theoretically I could calculate it with the EndAt and StartAt values but they are no longer filled with data and always will be null (see documentation).

So all of this is done so far with the `Google.Apis.YouTube.v3`. The code I currently have:

```
        var PlaylistItemRequest = YouTubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet,contentDetails");
        PlaylistItemRequest.PlaylistId = Find;
        PlaylistItemRequest.MaxResults = 50;

        List<Song> PlaylistItems = new List<Song>();

        while (true)
        {
            var PlaylistItemResponse = await PlaylistItemRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var playlistitem in PlaylistItemResponse.Items)
                PlaylistItems.Add(new Song(playlistitem.Snippet.Title, playlistitem.ContentDetails.EndAt, playlistitem.ContentDetails.StartAt, $"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={playlistitem.Id}", playlistitem.Snippet.Thumbnails.Default__.Url, DateTime.UtcNow, null, user.Id));

            if (PlaylistItemResponse.NextPageToken == null) break;

            PlaylistItemRequest.PageToken = PlaylistItemResponse.NextPageToken;
        }
```

Then I thought I could just do something like that, because this would give me the duration of the video:

`var request = YouTubeService.Videos.List("snippet,contentDetails,statistics");`

The problem is that I would need to send this for each song in the playlist and I do not want to risk to break the Google API ratelimits. Since 200 requests are a lot.

Any help is appreciated!

Note: I would need a solution with no manual delay if possible.

Comment: You can do a Videos.List request up to 50 IDs at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot!@johnh10